# apache php access rights configuration

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server

I am a complete apache and co newb.
Currently it serves only the default page.
On the default page, the user can not list the directory or files.
When I create a directory, say

```
/var/www/foobar
```

and place files in it, the user can by doing:

```
 www.mydomain.org/foobar
```

see the contents of the directory.
I run pretty much the default configuration.
on Directory "/", I have FollowSymlinks and AllowOverride(none)
on what DocumentRoot points to I have Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
and "allow from all" set.

My questions are:

1. Can I stop people from listing subdirectories?
2. Can people, if I do not change the configuration, in some way read the php files in there? (I mean not the rendered page, I mean the .php page source.)

Pointers to good resources about this would also be nice.

Thx in Advance.

Comment: Perhaps this should be on serverfault instead?

Also, knowing which distribution of linux would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, but I got confused with all the different sites. I usually only use stackoverflow. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can stop the SERVER from listing files in a folder. Read about apaches [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex).
2. Maybe, if your server supports PHP and has it enabled, it shouldn't displayed the source code. It should display the rendered PHP script.

Also, I like using [AskApache](http://www.askapache.com/) as a guide but Google is a lifesaver, too.